# Hide and Show through Mouseover doesn't work. Any idea why my code doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, html

Super simple code, but I can't make it work.
Trying to hide and show my div player, but can't make it work.

Thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".player").mouseover(function() {
    $(".player").hide("blind", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
  });
  $(".player").mouseout(function() {
    $(".player").show("blind", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player">
  ssdssdffsf
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery's `hide()` sets the `display` CSS property of the element to `none`, resulting in the `mouseout` event being instantly triggered, as the element doesn't take up any space anymore and therefore the mouse is technically no longer over it.

What you can do is set CSS `opacity: 0` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".player").mouseover(function() {
    $(".player").css({
      opacity: 0
    });
  });
  $(".player").mouseout(function() {
    $(".player").css({
      opacity: '' // empty string resets a CSS property, you could also use 1 explicitly here
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player">
  ssdssdffsf
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Connum for the quick answer. I wanted to get the effect " ("blind", { direction: "down" }, 1000) " inside the show() or hide() brackets. Do you know a solution how I could include this effect?

Comment: That will cause the same issue. As soon as the div animated to 0 height, the mouseout event will be triggered, resulting in an endless animation forth and back. That means that your UI logic is flawed and you should think of something else, like a button toggling the state of the player element.

Comment: Hey Connum, marked your answer as correct, as it helped for the first answer. Do you think you could help me with the new answer tho? Can't find a way to solve it, neither by adding css, even though it sounds so simple, hmmm

Comment: As I said, you'll have to think through your logic. When you hide an element on hover, it will immediately trigger the mouseout event. If you stop listening to the mouse out event, how is your user ever going to make the player element visible again?